# Json.JsonSerializationException : Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, json-deserialization

My problem is that I'm getting this error when I try to deserialize my API json response. 
 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Entities.JsonDataType]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

My json data return something like this

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "USD Amerikan Doları",
      "buying": "6.6920",
      "selling": "6.6995"
    },
    {
      "name": "EUR Euro",
      "buying": "7.7322",
      "selling": "7.7393"
    },
    {
      "name": "GBP İngiliz Sterlini",
      "buying": "8.5933",
      "selling": "8.6041"
    },
    "..."
  ]
}
```

My class properties:

```
public class JsonDataType
    {

        //public string name { get; set; }

        //public string buying { get; set; }

        //public string selling { get; set; }

        public bool success { get; set; }
        public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string buying { get; set; }
        public string selling { get; set; }
    }
```

And I'm getting the error when I deserialize:

```
List<JsonDataType> X = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonDataType>>(response.Content);
```

Also I tried these codes but none of them working

```
    JsonDataType X = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
```

```
IEnumerable<Result> X = (JsonDataType)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Result>>(response.Content, typeof(JsonDataType));
```

```
List<Result> X = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDataType>(response.Content, typeof(Result));
```

If someone could help me i will be so peaceful.
Thanks for your time in advance (✿◠‿◠)

Comment: That JSON isn't an array/list. It should work if you use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDataType>(response.Content);`

Comment: I see data as a string already . But i want convert to List<Result>  type. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: The response of the code I showed would give you a value that you can do `foreach(var result in response.result) { ... }`

Comment: This is what i'm looking for i finally found it. JsonDataType X = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDataType>(response.Content);  Really thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer

```
JsonDataType X = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDataType>(response.Content);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include an explanation. Code only answers have little long-term value